# Override layout gloably in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can one override a layout set depending on a query parameter sent in the request even if the layout is set in the action?

For Example,

```
#application_controller
layout :choose_layout

def choose_layout
  params[:layout]
end


#pages_controller

def show
  render html: page.content, layout: page.layout
end
```

in this example, the layout is set to `page.layout` instead of what was set in the application controller because the layout proc runs before as a before action.

**What I need to achieve is to have some code in the application controller that would override any set layout if the parameter is set and keeps working normally if it is not.**

Also, I have to admit this is a hack and not the cleanest way to do things. I need to do it in this way to avoid changing this all over the code base while still having different themes depending on where we are serving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `render` method like this and add the layout that you want when calling the parent `render` method.

```
#application_controller

def render(*args)
  return super unless params[:layout].present?

  opts = args.extract_options!
  super(*args, opts.merge(layout: params[:layout]))
end
```